# PrefixTree insert method

Tags: python

So I'm constructing a prefix tree where if I insert a value 'cat', the internal nodes leading up to 'cat' looks like: [] -> ['c'] -> ['c', 'a'] -> ['c', 'a', 't'] -> 'cat' where the last value is a leaf. However my method is doing [] -> ['c'] -> ['a'] -> ['t'] -> 'cat' instead of what I want.

```
class SimplePrefixTree:
    def __init__(self, weight_type: str) -> None:
        self.value = []
        self.weight = 0
        self.subtrees = []
        self.weight_type = weight_type

    def insert(self, value: Any, weight: float, prefix: List) -> None:
        new_node = self.c_node(value, weight, prefix)
            self.subtrees.append(new_node)

    def c_node(self, value: Any, weight: float, prefix: List) -> Any:
        new_node = SimplePrefixTree(self.weight_type)
        new_node.value = new_node.value + [prefix[0]]
        new_node.weight = weight
        new_node.insert(value, weight, prefix[1:])
        return new_node
```

I found the problem is if I do this recursively, I can never use the previous level node value and add to it, a new node always starts with []. How can I change this?

Comment: Please do **not** deface your question. Not fair to the folks who answered your question or to future visitors to this site with a similar problem.

Comment: I'm afraid that still you cannot deface your question. Once asked, the question becomes property of the site as per the site's [terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) which you agreed to on joining: `"All materials displayed or performed on the public Network, including but not limited to text, graphics, .... illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, and animations .... are the property of Stack Overflow"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place where you're changing the `value` of your prefix tree is here:

```
new_node = SimplePrefixTree(self.weight_type)
new_node.value = new_node.value + [prefix[0]]
```

Not what you're doing. You're initializing a new `SimplePrefixTree()` with `value = []`. Then, you're appending `[prefix[0]]` to that. No wonder only the contents of the thing is only ever one element; you're only ever telling it to add one element!

What you seem to want here is to add all preceding elements to `value`, and then add `prefix[0]` afterwards. What you can do, then, is add `self.value` to `new_node.value` before adding `[prefix[0]]`.

```
new_node.value = new_node.value + self.value + [prefix[0]]
```

The object that `self` refers to is the parent of the new node you're creating. Thus, `self.value` already has the first few elements of the prefix tree. So we copy them and then add `prefix[0]` afterwards. So it goes like this (let's say `prefix = 'cat'`:

```
root.value    = []
child_1.value = [] + root.value    + [prefix[0]] = [] + []         + ['c'] = ['c']
child_2.value = [] + child_1.value + [prefix[1]] = [] + ['c']      + ['a'] = ['c', 'a']
child_3.value = [] + child_2.value + [prefix[2]] = [] + ['c', 'a'] + ['t'] = ['c', 'a', 't']
...
```

Comment: I learned that parents have access to subtree values, but subtrees don't know who the parent is, is this considered that?

Comment: The subtree doesn't know who its parent is, true. But when you're *creating* the subtree (`new_node`) you're not *in* the subtree - you're in its parent. Of course the parent knows who itself is.